# Connection between Bluetooth Module HC-05 and Flutter app with android and Windows

Tags: android, flutter, windows, arduino, bluetooth

I need to make a connection between Bluetooth Module HC-05 and the flutter project, I need to make it work on Android and Windows (Desktop) platforms.

I previously searched for packages on [pub.dev](https://pub.dev/) and found packages that only work on one of the platforms I want. One time I find Android only and another time I find Windows. Some packages are outdated and do not work with modern Fultter or Android SDK versions,
so what should I do now? Is there any solution to this issue?